# Groupby Ordering and Single row selecting

Tags: sql, postgresql

Immediate disclaimer: Its been a few years since I seriously did SQL, returning recently.

Given a table:

```
logical_id, instance_id, node_id, state, time_stamp
1, 1, a, starting, 1300003234
2, 1, a, up, 1300003235
**3, 1, b, starting, 1300003237**
4, 1, a, completed, 1300003239
5, 1, a, shutdown, 1300003240
```

Given a specific instance_id (e.g. 1) I want to get the last state record (single row- highlighted in bold) of the authoritive node, the authoritive node is the most recent one to have entered a 'starting', in the absence of any node entering a starting stage it just the most recent node to be logged.

I figured I do some form group by node_id *with* order by (rather than filter) boolean(state = 'starting), time_stamp desc, but I cant seem to get this right, in addition I think the group by would have to come after the ordering.

Im using postgres 9.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will retrieve the most recent stating node, if it exists, otherwise it will simply return the most recent non-starting node.

```
SELECT U.logical_id, U.instance_id, U.node_id, U.state, U.time_stamp
FROM 
(
 SELECT M1.logical_id, M1.instance_id, M1.node_id, M1.state, M1.time_stamp, 1 AS node_type
 FROM MyTable M1
 WHERE M1.instance_id=1 AND M1.state='starting' 
 ORDER BY M1.time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1

 UNION

 SELECT M2.logical_id, M2.instance_id, M2.node_id, M2.state, M2.time_stamp, 0 AS node_type
 FROM MyTable M2
 WHERE M2.instance_id=1 
 ORDER BY M2.time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1
) AS U
ORDER BY U.node_type DESC  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: will need to test but presuming this setup I can do this over a set by replacing the magic 1's with u.logical_id, looks promising will report back

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, once doesnt need a groupby, instead ORDER BY (state='starting') desc, time_stamp desc LIMIT 1 seems to do the trick **for a single record only.** In end I choose the answer that work sbest over a set by Holger

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table where instance_id = 1 and time_stamp = max(time_stamp) and state = 'starting';

Have you tried this route?  Timestamp or the interval is long when get to the root of it. This might help as working with date is one of those things someone should never try to remember

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html